# Return bool value based on enum selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

So I have searched ad infinitum and am only getting more confused.  I have a C# MVC application in which I have a class "Income".  I have input below what I am trying to accomplish but just cant seem to figure out.

```
public enum PayType
{
    Hourly, Salary, Commission
}

public class Income
{
    public PayType PayType {get; set;}
    public bool IsOvertimeEligible 
        { get 
            { if(PayType.Hourly)
                 {
                      return true;
                 }
             return false;
            }
         }
}
```

I have tried "typeof" and several other things but can't seem to move off zero.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: _"can't seem to move off zero"_ what does that mean? Where have you tried what?

Comment: You are probably confused because your property of type `PayType` is also named `PayType`. You want compare the *value* of the `PayType` property to a enum value `PayType.Hourly`. Also. whenever you return `true` or `false` from an `if`, you can simply return the expression (because the expression itself is of type `bool` and evaluates to `true` or `false`) .

Comment: Please mention the error and the line where it happens next time you ask a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: There was no error, only a compiler error.

Comment: Thanks to those that weren't pretensious jerks.

Comment: @BartDaley - you ask an incomplete question and expect everyone to understand what you meant and when someone gives you polite pointers on how to improve your question and therefore *your* chances of getting better answers, you call them jerks?

Comment: A poite pointers and constructive feedback is great and I upvoted each helpful user that provided meaningful feedback.  Short, sarcastic responses from obnoxious elitists are not welcome or beneficial.  Clearly there was enough information to obtain meaningful responses.

Comment: @BartDaley - Where do you see pretentiousness or sarcasm? And yes, you were lucky that other people were nice enough to try and figure out, what your actual problem is. They had to, because *you didn't tell what it is*. Maybe you'll keep getting lucky like that. Probably not. In any case, if you want an answer it is *in your best interest* to provide as much and detailed information as possible, so people who spend their free time helping others have to spend as little of it as possible. Otherwise they might say a question with no effort put in doesn't deserve effort to be answered.

Answer (score 4):

`PayType.Hourly` is a member of the `enum` `PayType` whereas `this.PayType` (`this.` is optional but included for clarity) is a member of the `class` `Income`. Neither of these can be used as a condition of the `if` statement, but the equality comparison (`==`) of the two results in a `bool` so can. Therefore, change

```
if(PayType.Hourly)
```

to

```
if (this.PayType == PayType.Hourly)
```

to make this compile.

---

You can simplify the get call by getting rid of the superfluous `if` statment

```
public bool IsOvertimeEligible
{
    get { return this.PayType == PayType.Hourly; }
}
```

i.e.

```
if (condition)
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

can just be

```
return condition;
```

Comment: @BartDaley Good to hear! Please use the tick button at the side of the answer to indicate as such (you also get 2+ rep for doing so)!

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
public bool IsOvertimeEligible
{
    get
    {
        return this.PayType == PayType.Hourly;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(PayType == PayType.Hourly)
```